# SyntaxError: f-string: expecting '}'

Tags: python, syntax-error, f-string

I have a problem here.

I don't know why this code does not work.

```
newline = '\n'
tasks_choosen = ['markup', 'media', 'python_api', 'script', 'style', 'vue']
print(f'{ newline }### Initializing project with the following tasks: { ' '.join(tasks_choosen) }.{ newline }')
```

Error:

> File "new-gulp-project.py", line 85
>
> print(f'{ newline }### Initializing project with the following tasks: { ' '.join(tasks_choosen) }.{ newline }')
>
> SyntaxError: f-string: expecting '}'

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Try using " for the outermost '

Comment: You are using `'` both to delimit the outer string and the inner one. Try changing one of these to `"`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because you use single quotes twice you get:
`print(f'{ newline }### Initializing project with the following tasks: { '` instead of

```py
print(f'{ newline }### Initializing project with the following tasks: { ' '.join(tasks_choosen) }.{ newline }')
```

Use double quotes inside:

```py
print(f'{ newline }### Initializing project with the following tasks: { " ".join(tasks_choosen) }.{ newline }')
```

Comment: Oh, you are right! Really missed it. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 4):

Python is getting confused as you are using ' ' (single-quotes) for the f-string and ' ' (single-quotes) just before the join, so its getting confused as to where your f-string actually ends. Replace the ' ' with " " just before the .join() and it should work :)